# Parameterized Factories Using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, factory-pattern, ninject.web.mvc

How to make Ninject to instantiate object based on variable on run time?.

I am trying to inject the correct Repository in The Controller action - MVC 3 - based on parameter come from user input. If user input "BMW" it would bind `ICarRepository`  to `BMWRepository` , and if he input "KIA" `KiaRepository` will be injected.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResult(FormCollection values)
{
    string carModel  = values["model"];

    ICarRepository myRepository = RepositoryFactory.getRepository(carModel);

    .....
}
```

This is known by switch/case noob instantiation or Parameterized Factories, and i know how to do it manually without Ninject , Check the 4 approaches explained here [Exploring Factory Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37547/Exploring-Factory-Pattern)

My question is how to do it with Ninject?

Comment: Is https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-Referencing-Named-Bindings any use for your actual case (probably not) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could inject an [Abstract Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementingAnAbstractFactory.aspx) (probably just a `Func<string,ICarRepository>`) and then have it all implemented via adding the following to your `RegisterServices`:

```
Bind<ICarRepository>().To<KiaRepository>().Named("KIA")
Bind<ICarRepository>().To<BmwRepository>().Named("BMW")
Bind<Func<string,ICarRepository>>()
    .ToMethod( ctx=> name => ctx.Get<ICarRepository>( name));
```

In your ctor:

```
class MyController
{
    readonly Func<string,ICarRepository> _createRepository;

    public MyController(Func<string,ICarRepository> createRepository)
    {
        _createRepository = createRepository;
    }
```

Then, in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResult(FormCollection values)
{
    string carModel  = values["model"];

     using( ICarRepository myRepository = _createRepository( carModel)) 
     {
            ... 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to call it from controller Action?

Comment: @user968159 you add `Func<string,ICarRepository> createRepository` to your arguments, assign it to a `readonly` field, and then do `using( var repo = _createRepository( carModel)) { ... }`

Comment: Giving That `Func<string,ICarRepository>` will be binned to  ctx.Get<ICarRepository>( name) , In IBMWRepository should i decorate it with name attribute and set its value to "BMW"?
My understanding to ctx.Get<ICarRepository>( name) is it passes name to the constructor.

Comment: @user968159 No, the way that I'm doing it, the first arg to the func is used to identify the name of the binding. (So you'll need to `Bind<ICarRepository>().To<KiaRepository>().Named("KIA")` for ti all to connect up. Edited this in. BTW have you looked at ninject.extensions.factory ? Unless your real problem is exactly as you have asked, most of this kind of stuff is best accomplished with it

Comment: Yes it Works now, and this is exactly what i am looking for.
Thanks alot Ruben