# Ninject how to avoid array injection for multiple name bindings

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Review the following code, where to take care of cases with both single and named binding for an interface, an abstract factory is used as suggested here

[Parameterized Factories Using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057142/parameterized-factories-using-ninject)

Challenge here is, I need to introduce `IEnumerable<T> bankingOperationList`, instead of `T bankingOperationList`, since for named binding it will always use the abstract factory injection, `Func<string,T> bankingOperationFunc`, but if I don't use `IEnumerable<T>` suggested above it leads to exception, due to this for even non named single binding, I need to use something like:
`bankingOperationList.FirstOrDefault().Withdraw()`, even when I know there will only be one dependency.
Another challenge is, for some named bindings it has 30 - 40 bindings in few cases, which will be unnecessarily filled, when I can default `T bankingOperationList` to null, as it is not required. Please let me know, if the issue needs further clarification. Working Console project underneath.

```
public interface IBankingOperation
{
    void Withdraw();
}

public class BankingOperationOne : IBankingOperation
{
    public BankingOperationOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: One :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation One");
    }
}

public class BankingOperationTwo : IBankingOperation
{
    public BankingOperationTwo() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: Two :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation Two");
    }
}

// Ninject Bindings
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IBankingOperation>().To<BankingOperationOne>()
                                 .Named("A");

        Bind<IBankingOperation>().To<BankingOperationTwo>()
                                 .Named("B");

        Bind<Func<string,IBankingOperation>>().ToMethod(ctx => name => ctx.Kernel.Get<IBankingOperation>(name));
    }
}

public class BankTran<T> where T : IBankingOperation
{
    private IEnumerable<T> bankingOperationList = null;

    private Func<string,T> bankingOperationFunc;

    public BankTran(IEnumerable<T> boList = null, 
                    Func<string,T> boFunc = null)
    {
        bankingOperationList = boList;
        bankingOperationFunc = boFunc;
    }

    public void DoOperation(string identifier = null)
    {
        if(bankingOperationFunc != null)        
            bankingOperationFunc(identifier).Withdraw();
        else
            bankingOperationList.FirstOrDefault().Withdraw();       

        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Successful ");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); // Load from Bindings (derived from NinjectModule)

        var transaction = kernel.Get<BankTran<IBankingOperation>>();

        transaction.DoOperation("A");
    }
}
```

**Edit 1, based on response by jbl**

```
public interface IBankingOperation<T>
{
    void Withdraw();
}

public class BankingOperationOne : IBankingOperation<TestOne>
{
    public BankingOperationOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: One :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation One");
    }
}

public class BankingOperationTwo : IBankingOperation<TestTwo>
{
    public BankingOperationTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: Two :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation Two");
    }
}

public class TestOne { }

public class TestTwo { }

// Ninject Bindings
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().Named("A");

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().Named("B");

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(BankTran<TestOne>));

        Bind<Func<string, IBankingOperation<TestOne>>>().ToMethod(ctx => name => ctx.Kernel.Get<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>(name));

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestTwo>>().To<BankingOperationTwo>();
    }
}

public class BankTran<T> where T : class
{
    private IBankingOperation<T> bankingOperation;

    private Func<string, IBankingOperation<T>> bankingOperationFunc;

    public BankTran(IBankingOperation<T> bo = null,
                    Func<string, IBankingOperation<T>> boFunc = null)
    {
        bankingOperation = bo;
        bankingOperationFunc = boFunc;
    }

    public void DoOperation(string identifier = null)
    {
        if (bankingOperationFunc != null && identifier != null)
            bankingOperationFunc(identifier).Withdraw();
        else if (bankingOperation != null)
            bankingOperation.Withdraw();

        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Successful ");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { AllowNullInjection = true});

        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); // Load from Bindings (derived from NinjectModule)

        var transaction = kernel.Get<BankTran<TestOne>>("A"); // Not Working 

        // var transaction = kernel.Get<BankTran<TestOne>>(); // Working 

        transaction.DoOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Injecting a `Func` is one way to get the job done. Using a [strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971691/) is another. This would be a cleaner solution to having the "list" on hand. That said, it isn't really clear what issue you are trying to solve - is it getting the "default" operation from the list?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Issue is multiple bindings for same type will be handled by `Func<string,T>`, other one `IEnumerable<T>` is not used, its required only for one to one / unique / unnamed binding, but still i need a collection, otherwise for named bindings lead to exception, they are unnecessarily filled. Please run the code and try `T bankingOperation` instead of `IEnumerable<T> bankingOperationList` in `BankTran<T>`, you will get the issue I am talking about

Comment: @NightOwl888 I reviewed the solution that you provided, which obviate the need of `Func`, by `ICarFactory[]` itself finding the correct object, but that way I am able to make the current solution work elegantly, I just wanted to avoid named binding requirement to fill in a collection when is doing its job, but Ninject remains clue less in that case and wants collection to fill

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `BankingOperationOne` is your default behaviour,
adding the following line in your Load method should allow to replace the `IEnumerable<T>` with `T` in your BankTran constructor :

```
Bind<IBankingOperation>().To<BankingOperationOne>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(BankTran<>));
```

Another solution would be to just define a named binding for default behaviour

```
Bind<IBankingOperation>().To<BankingOperationOne>().Named("__DefaultBehaviour");
```

then

```
 public void DoOperation(string identifier = "__DefaultBehaviour")
        {
            if (bankingOperationFunc != null)
                bankingOperationFunc(identifier).Withdraw();

            Console.WriteLine("Transaction Successful ");
        }
```

**Edit :**

You should use the [Ninject.Extenstions.Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) nuget package.
Using this package, the following code seems to fullfill you requirements.

```
public interface IBankingOperation<T>
{
    void Withdraw();
}

public interface IBankingOperationFactory<T>
{
    IBankingOperation<T> GetBankingOperation(string name);
}

public class BankingOperationOne : IBankingOperation<TestOne>
{
    public BankingOperationOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: One :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation One");
    }
}

public class BankingOperationTwo : IBankingOperation<TestTwo>
{
    public BankingOperationTwo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Constructor :: Two :: Empty");
    }

    public void Withdraw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Money Withdrawl Operation Two");
    }
}

public class TestOne { }

public class TestTwo { }

// Ninject Bindings
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().Named("A");

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().Named("B");

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>().To<BankingOperationOne>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(BankTran<TestOne>));

        Bind<IBankingOperationFactory<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>>().ToFactory();

        Bind<IBankingOperation<TestTwo>>().To<BankingOperationTwo>();
    }
}

public class BankTran<T> where T : class
{
    private IBankingOperation<T> bankingOperation;

    private IBankingOperationFactory<T> _bankingOperationFactory;

    public BankTran(IBankingOperation<T> bo = null,
                    IBankingOperationFactory<T> bankingOperationFactory = null)
    {
        bankingOperation = bo;
        _bankingOperationFactory = bankingOperationFactory;
    }

    public void DoOperation(string identifier = null)
    {
        if (_bankingOperationFactory != null && identifier != null)
            _bankingOperationFactory.GetBankingOperation(identifier).Withdraw();
        else if (bankingOperation != null)
            bankingOperation.Withdraw();

        Console.WriteLine("Transaction Successful ");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { AllowNullInjection = true });

        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); // Load from Bindings (derived from NinjectModule)

        var transaction = kernel.Get<BankTran<TestOne>>();

        transaction.DoOperation();
        transaction.DoOperation("A");
        transaction.DoOperation("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, check out the edit in the question marked as **Edit 1, based on response by jbl** Your code helped me in running a part as marked in main method without an explicit Name, but it doesn't still helps in running a version with Name like "A", which is my primary challenge

Comment: @MrinalKamboj shouldn't the not working line in your edited example be `var transaction = kernel.Get<IBankingOperation<TestOne>>("A");` ?

Comment: That's hat I have marked as non working, just that I have included that part in the code, so that you can run and review the error. Other part Without "A" is working, as suggested in the comment above.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj : ok I think I understood. I edited my answer with a running example.